# Apache Camel REST DSL sending some data along with each response

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and want to implement the following scenario:

I am developing REST services using camel REST-DSL and with each response, I have to send some data(an integer count representing the number of new notifications).

Following is the code how I am using REST DSL:

```
        rest("/rest1").description("Rest1 service")                           
        .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")

        .post("/addMultiple").typeList(Map.class).to("bean:somebean1?method=someMethod1(${body})")
        .post("/add").to("bean:somebean1?method=someMethod2(${body})")

        .get("/status").description("Find all request by status").outTypeList(Request.class)
        .to("bean:somebean1?method=someMethod3(${header.status})") ; 

         rest("/rest2").description("Rest2 service")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")

            .post("/add").type(FileBean.class).to("bean:someBean2?method=someMethod1(${body})")

            .get("/categories")
            .description("get all categories")
            .to("bean:someBean2?method=someMethod2()");
```

Here with each JSON response I am sending, I have to send some integer count for continuous update at client side.

What if I can have header and with each response I update it by setting new value.

Please advise on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the header in your bean, and use bean parameter binding to bind the `Map headers` so you can add the counter.

```
public String doSomething(String data, @Headers Map headers) {
   ...
}
```

See more details at

- http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html
- http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Another approach could be to use an on completion to add the header at the end of the routing (requires Camel 2.15 and use the before consumer mode)

- http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion

Comment: thanks @Claus Ibsen for your reply and time. I find onCompletion() method feasible for my scenario and I tried it with global scope but as I am using 2.14 it is not working. Sir can I use aggregationStratergy for this scenario where aggregating my counter with each response.

Comment: If you can set the header earlier you can also try the interceptor which you can use with 2.14 - http://camel.apache.org/intercept

Comment: Finally I updated my Camel to 2.15 and used onCompletion() method which worked for me.Thanks @Claus Ibsen.